# iptables: employ DROP or REJECT rules in non-'filters' tables, namely the NAT table?

Tags: iptables, firewall, linux-networking, nat, rules

For an [`iptables(8)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) firewall that is otherwise "properly locked down" in the `filter` table, is there any use to employ `DROP`, `REJECT` or similar, terminating, "blocking or disabling" rules in non-`filters` tables, namely the `NAT` table (or the `mangle`, `raw`, or `security` tables for that matter)?

**We specifically want to close *any*, *potential* "holes" in our firewall.**

`NAT`'s `POSTROUTING` chain does not accept a `DROP` or `REJECT` target on at least one of out team's systems:

```
$ iptables -t nat -P POSTROUTING DROP
iptables v1.6.1:
The "nat" table is not intended for filtering, the use of DROP is therefore inhibited.


Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
$
$ iptables -t nat -P POSTROUTING REJECT
iptables: Bad policy name. Run `dmesg' for more information.
$
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
$
```

Comment: I cross-posted to reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/gqjtfq/iptables_employ_drop_or_reject_rules_in/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Excerpt from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/gqjtfq/iptables_employ_drop_or_reject_rules_in/frt5gsm/):

"Packets can't skip the filter table, so dropping packets from an additional table doesn't buy you any additional security [...]"